# different browser and same css media min/max width

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, responsive-design, media-queries

So I'm having real problems dealing with this CSS thing.

I have 4 columns at 1920px (browser resolution) and then (decreasing resolution) 3 columns, 2 and one, simple. But the text inside and all the elements need to be perfect so there came up problems so I had to use MEDIA SCREEN restrictions for elements etc. Everything went well except details came up, chrome and firefox now both got different rendering for media screen queries.

I have for example this.

```
@media screen and and (min-width: 746px) and (max-width:765px) { 
    .agi {
        margin-bottom: 470px;
        /* this is because all my columns are one by one floated to the left and
           I want the last row to be below these columns in various browser resolutions */
    }
}
```

And it's different in Firefox (looks good) and different in Chrome (looks bad).

So I have found this CSS browser hack for chrome.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-width: 746px) and
(max-width:765px){ 
    .agi {
        margin-bottom: 470px;
    }
}
```

It is great because it works for Chrome, but then Firefox doesn't work because the `min-width` is same for Chrome and Firefox as well and here I don't know what to do. How can I achieve same visibility at both browsers. Should I try firefox css hack too? Is there another solution? Thank you.

Comment: Is your style [normalized](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to begin with?

Comment: _“Is there another solution?”_ – maybe; but until now, you haven’t even shown us a _real_ problem yet – you’re just saying that “something doesn’t work” as expected. So a full live example please (f.e. on http://jsfiddle.net/), and a detailed description what is wrong under what circumstances, please …

Comment: thank you for your input Kei, I will try the normalized style asap (when I get home, working) and to you CBroe: this is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jellyfren/wHP3d/; problems come when I try to enlarge the font or even type more characters for description etc then Chrome and Firefox both render something else (when changing the resolution) while I was trying to fix it for one browser then the other "shared" the editation too .. I really don't know what is the simplest way to display 4 columns, 3,2,1 - everytime aligned one by one, row by row without any glitch (without insane space between )